# PHP tag info needs update

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, tag-wiki

Latest version of PHP is listed as 5.3.3. It's 5.3.4 now.

Also, PHP 6 does not officially exist anymore - the development branch is called "trunk" and has no version as of yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've updated the wiki with the newer 5.3 release, but I don't know a better way to refer to the PHP 5.3.99 trunk

Comment: PHP development branch?

Comment: Sounds good, updated